# system("ssh user@hostname") command failed with status 256

Tags: c++, linux

My PC is installed with Redhat linux. When calling system() command, its Return was 0 for cmd1 and 256 for cmd2. 'cmd2' could run successfully in liunx terminal. RSA key was generated and copied so there was no need to type password when logging in to remote-hostname in terminal.

Can use system() call only because I do not have any authority to install API likes libssh or sshpass to connect remote-hostname.

```
char cmd1[256] = "echo hi";
char cmd2[256] = "ssh user@remote-hostname";
int Return = system(cmd2);
```

Below is from a simple example.sh file. The return was 127 (cannot be executed) after calling system command. Please help.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
ls -lt
```

`system("cd /path; sh -c example.sh");`

Comment: You can install libssh or sshpass  in you home directory: `rpm -ivh --prefix=~/opt libssh...rpm`.

Comment: Run your program under `strace` to see where ssh fails. Also note that you do not need special permissions to download, compile and link a library. If you need to do anything beyond mere basics, shoving everything through the ssh command will become painful.

Comment: Hello S.M, I am unfamiliar with rpm command. Below is return after '$ rpm -ivh --prefix=~/opt libssh...rpm' 
rpm: arguments to --prefix must begin with a /

Comment: Hi Botje, It is late now. I will do 'strace' tomorrow and update you. thank you for inputs

Comment: Hi Botje, after running 'strace', I realized that I had made a mistake. There were 3 PCs, remote PC-A, host PC-B, remote PC-C. Those commands were executing by PC-A that has very limited numbers of packages installed. The code above was trying to do "ssh user@remote-hostname" from PC-B to PC-C at PC-A environment. So it failed.